# Nginx uWSGI link server_name to domain for flask application

Tags: nginx, flask, dns, uwsgi, ubuntu-20.04

I have written a Flask website which I hosted with waitress on a Ubuntu 20.04 VM server at port 5000, but now I'd like to do it more properly with uWSGI/Nginx.

To learn uWSGI/Nginx I am following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04

Here in step 6 it tells my to configure Nginx as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domain www.my_domain;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

However if I now request the webpage for my domain, it only returns the default Nginx page.
But if I "hardcode" the public IP address of my server to the server_name:

```
server_name: my_domain www.my_domain MY_IP
```

Then it does show the correct page. I however have a feeling this is not the intended way to configure the server.

When I used the old waitress server i had told my DNS server redirect to `http://MY_IP:5000/`, but it is now set to redirect to `http://MY_IP/`. (with redirect mode 302)

So **my question is**, how should I set up my Domain name redirect or Nginx config so that it works without a "hardcoded" ip? Or is this something where I just need to wait the 48 hours for the DNS update to propagate?

Also an **auxiliary related question**, how do I make the browser url bar show the domain name instead of an IP address?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can go through my answer, hope it helps you as well

Regarding your question for URL name in browser, it will be there once DNS name is propagating properly and it shouldn't take more than 5-10 minutes.

Remove the IP from server name, its not supposed to be entered there.